# How to combine two loops to form a single query wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I have two loops and I need to combine them to a list

```
if ( have_rows('product_a')) :
    while ( have_rows('product_a') ) : the_row();

        echo get_field('product_name');

    endwhile;
endif;

if ( have_rows('product_b')) :
    while ( have_rows('product_b') ) : the_row();

        echo get_field('product_name');

    endwhile;
endif;
```

so the output would be like this, so combining them in a list

```
* product_a name
* product_B name
```

only if I could do this code below

```
if ( have_rows('product_a && product_b')) :
    while ( have_rows('product_a && product_b') ) : the_row();

        echo get_field('product_name');

    endwhile;
endif;
```

I have tried this code and its working but is this a good practice

```
if ( have_rows('product_a') || have_rows('product_b') ) :
while ( have_rows('product_a') || have_rows('product_b') ) : the_row();
```

and also another problem, **get_row_index()** only counts 1 instead of 2

Answer (score 1):

You could save the values in arrays and do the output later:

```
$array_counter = 0;
$product_a = [];
$product_b = [];

if ( have_rows('product_a')) :
    while ( have_rows('product_a') ) : the_row();

        $product_a[$counter] = get_field('product_name');
        $counter++;

    endwhile;
endif;

if ( have_rows('product_b')) :
    while ( have_rows('product_b') ) : the_row();

        $product_b[$counter] = get_field('product_name');
        $counter++;

    endwhile;
endif;
```

So you have your arrays. You now want to combine them in an alternating order:

```
$combined = [];
$length = count($product_a);
for ($i=0; $i < $length ; $i++) {
    $combined[] = $product_a[$i];
    $combined[] = $product_b[$i];
}
```

In each iteration, one item from each of the arrays will be appended to the combined-array. So you have you products in the right order.

Now you can just run through your array and output every value one by one:

```
$full_length = count($combined);
$counter = 0;
while ($counter < $full_length ) {
    echo '<li>'.$combined[$counter].'</li>';
}
```